# Android: swapping two elements on swipe, like Candy Crush

Tags: android, swap

I am developing my first Android game whose main screen is composed of a 4x4 array of views, each view contains an image and a text. When we **touch on a view and swipe it** to the position of a neighbor view, the two views are swapped, just like Candy Crush. I've been searching for a couple of days but I haven't found any appropriate solution. I concern about the following problems:

1. Should I use **GridView** or simply an **array of views** for such swapping?
2. **What kinds of event** should I process for this requirement?
3. How can I add **animation** so that two exchanged elements seem to have a real **moving effect**.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[This Link](https://www.journaldev.com/23208/android-recyclerview-drag-and-drop) should point you in the right direction. Note this will also work with GridViews. You just have to add your desired rules for filtering which items may/may not be swapped with eachother.